# Scrollable Custom View Compose (Canvas)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Can't resolve the problem with scrolling a Custom View in Compose.

I have a Canvas nested in a Column with fillMaxSize() modifier.
In Canvas I also use fillMaxSize() modifier (or size() with fixed value, doesn't matter)

I draw a vertical line that can be higher than screen size. And want, if this vertical line is higher, make canvas scrollable, but I can't. Any methods like verticalScroll(), scrollable() has no effects. I'm trying to make height of Canvas higher and use scrollable modifier, but it does no effect also (when I check "size" variable of DrawScope, it's always 1630 on Pixel 4).

Please help.

My code (Simplified and this method will be nested in Column):

```
@Composable
fun DrawTimeLine(list: List<Unit>){
    
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .scrollable(rememberScrollState(), Orientation.Vertical)
        .padding(
            top = Dimens.DEFAULT_MARGIN,
            bottom = Dimens.BOTTOM_BAR_SIZE,
            start = Dimens.DEFAULT_MARGIN
        )){
        
        var offsetY = 0f
        val offsetX = 0f
        
        val increaseValue = 150f

        fun drawTimePoint() {
            drawCircle(
                color = Color.White,
                radius = 15.dp.value,
                center = Offset(offsetX, offsetY)
            )
        }

        fun drawTimeLine() {
            drawLine(
                color = Color.White,
                start = Offset(offsetX, offsetY),
                end = Offset(offsetX, offsetY + increaseValue),
                strokeWidth = 5.dp.value
            )
            offsetY += increaseValue
        }
        
        list.forEach { 
            drawTimePoint()
            drawTimeLine()
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: @RaBaKa78 added :)